# button which should disappear, php/html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm making an online store and I need to make a button which should include a link to the new page, and after disappears forever from all pages of the store.

Until now I have this code:

```
<input class="button" value="Press to Register" type="submit" name="submit" tabIndex="8" onClick = "this.style.visibility= 'hidden'; window.open('/my-account/','_top')">

<style type="text/css">
.button {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        display: inline-block;
        background: #459300 url('../images/orange_bg.jpg') top left repeat-x;
        border: 1px solid #459300 ;
        padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;

                }

.button:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
                }

.button:active {
        padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
               }
</style>
```

So the button now disappears, relocates me on a new page, but on the new page I still can see it.

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Are you trying to log in the user?

Comment: If you have the button in the a dinamically loaded header you should move it from there.

Comment: Kind off, It is registration button, if a user press it then the new page with registration form appears. So I don't want to that this button will be shown again, especially after registration or if a user is loged in

Comment: the project is here: gazberg.eu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using WordPress login. You should be able to hide your button by detecting if user is logged in and make an if statement where you have your button. Like this:

```php
<?php
  if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
?>
      <input class="button" value="Press to Register" type="submit" name="submit" tabIndex="8" onClick = "this.style.visibility= 'hidden'; window.open('/my-account/','_top')">
<?php 
 }
?>
```

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for ! Works great ! Thank you very much ! !

Comment: @O.Telegin, you should accept this answer if it fits your needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create cookie or LocalStorage

```
<input class="button" value="Press to Register" id="hideme" type="submit" name="submit" tabindex="8" onclick="this.style.visibility = 'hidden'; window.open('/my-account/', '_top'); localStorage.setItem('hideforever', 1);">
    <script>
        if (localStorage.getItem('hideforever') == 1) {
            document.getElementById("hideme").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .button {
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            display: inline-block;
            background: #459300 url('../images/orange_bg.jpg') top left repeat-x;
            border: 1px solid #459300;
            padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .button:hover {
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .button:active {
                padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
            }
    </style>
```

Comment: This is really not the best solution. The button is still there and can be accesed by everyone on the site even though is hidden.

Comment: Yes this is not the best way but as @O.Telegin is using CSS & Javascript for hidding the button thatswhy I answered in CSS and Javascript way Otherwise PHP way is good to implement